# "Das stört mich, ich muss zugeben" vs "Das stört mich, muss ich zugeben"

Tags: word-order, subordinate-clause

Ich habe einem Muttersprachler die Frage gestellt, welcher dieser Sätze korrekt sei, und er hat gesagt, "Das stört mich, muss ich zugeben" entspricht der korrekten Wortstellung.

Nichtsdestoweniger kann ich den Grund dafür nicht begreifen. Wenn man "dass" bei einem Nebensatz weglässt, sollte sich der Satz syntaktisch nicht so verhalten, als wäre er ein Hauptsatz? Wenn nicht, dann habe ich das bis zum heutigen Tag falsch angenommen...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Das stört mich" ist der Nebensatz (ein Objektsatz um genau zu sein).

"... muss ich zugeben" ist der Hauptsatz. Der Objektsatz ist der erste Satzteil, daher folgt das Verb (bzw. die Verbklammer *muss ... zugeben*) unmittelbar.

In der Variante mit "dass" ändert sich die Wortreihenfolge im Nebensatz. Im Hauptsatz bleibt sie gleich:

> Dass mich das stört, muss ich zugeben.

Man vergleiche die Varianten mit Objektsatz am Ende:

> Ich muss zugeben, dass mich das stört.
>
> Ich muss zugeben, das stört mich.

Hier wird die 1.Position, die vorher der Nebensatz innehatte, vom Subjekt eingenommen.

Comment: Die zweite Variante geht so nicht, weil Du da zweimal Hauptsatz-Struktur hast. Allenfalls wäre "Ich muss zugeben: das stört mich" oder eine vergleichbare Kombination, die einen zweiten Hauptsatz zulässt, möglich.