# Verbstellung im Hauptsatz bei vorangestelltem Nebensatz (wenn das Adverb "dann" fehlt)

Tags: word-order, grammaticality, adverb, subordinate-clause

Meine Frau hat heute einen Zwischentest beim Sprachkurs gehabt und folgendes geschrieben:

> Wenn ich Hunger habe, ich koche das Essen.

Die Lehrerin hat sie korrigiert:

> Wenn ich Hunger habe, **koche ich** das Essen.

Uns wurde immer wiederholt, dass die Verben im Deutschen immer an der zweiten oder der letzten Stelle stehen müssen. Da fehlt das Adverb *dann* im Hauptsatz, somit schrieb meine Frau es richtig, oder?

Die Lehrerin begründete ihre Behauptung damit, dass das Adverb *dann* im Satz schon gemeint ist.

Und noch die Frage:

> Wenn ich Hunger habe, ich koche das Essen.

Ist der Satz grammatikalisch inkorrekt, oder ist eine solche Schreibweise im Prinzip erlaubt? Ich meine, wenn man an einer Universität ist und so schreibt, wäre das ein klarer Fehler?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When does a verb come second?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24723/when-does-a-verb-come-second)

Comment: I would like to have my question answered in German, to show the answer to my wife's teacher.

Comment: @RHa Unterschiedliche Sprachen - [kein Duplikat](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/807/what-to-do-with-duplicate-questions-in-another-language)

Comment: In dieser Frage geht es um dasselbe Phänomen: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/49216/das-st%c3%b6rt-mich-ich-muss-zugeben-vs-das-st%c3%b6rt-mich-muss-ich-zugeben

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Wenn ich Hunger habe, koche ich das Essen.

Das Verb *kochen* steht hier an zweiter Position.

[*Wenn ich Hunger habe*]<sub>1</sub>, [*koche*]<sub>2</sub> *ich das Essen.*

Wenn die Aussage - wie hier - mit einem Nebensatz beginnt, gilt der gesamte Nebensatz als Position 1.

Nun könntest du sagen, dass im Falle von

> Wenn ich Hunger habe, **dann** koche ich das Essen.

das Verb nicht mehr an zweiter Stelle steht. Aber Adverbien (dann), die nach Konditionalsätzen auftreten (wenn ...), stellen keine eigenen Satzglieder dar, sondern dienen als Korrelate für den vorausgegangenen Nebensatz<sup>1</sup>. Das kann man sich leicht merken, weil man dieses *dann* ja auch weglassen kann. Auch in diesem Fall steht also das Verb *koche* an zweiter Position.

> Wenn ich Hunger habe, ich koche das Essen.
> Ist der Satz grammatisch inkorrekt, oder ist eine solche Schreibweise im Prinzip erlaubt?

Das ist grammatisch nicht korrekt und diese Schreibweise daher auch im Prinzip nicht erlaubt.

---

1 nachzulesen in [Habermann et al.: Fit für das Bachelorstudium, Grundwissen Grammatik. Dudenverlag, 2009.](https://www.worldcat.org/title/duden-fit-fur-das-bachelorstudium-buch/oclc/320533060)

Comment: Das Argument, dass *dann* kein Satzglied sei, weil man es weglassen könne, verfängt nicht. Meines Erachtens wird das Satzgefüge durch das "dann" mit Zeigefunktion (und wohl auch in der Funktion eines sog. Korrelats) anakoluthisch aufgebrochen.

Comment: Dass man das *dann* weglassen kann, ist eine Merkhilfe dafür, es nicht als Satzglied mitzuzählen, keine sprachwissenschaftliche Begründung.

Comment: Die "Merkregel" spannt aber den Karren vor das Pferd: es war gerade die Frage des Originalposts, ob *dann* weggelassen werden kann, ohne dass sich die Wortstellung ändert (welche der Fragesteller für sich mit nein beantwortet hat).

Comment: Indem man *dann* nicht mitzählt, gelangt man, was die Erklärung angeht, insofern vom Regen der Begründung der Lehrerin (*dann* sei mitgemeint) in die Traufe (*dann* könne weggelassen werden). Die Antwort stellt ohne Zweifel gut dar, dass der Nebensatz das Vorfeld besetzt -- um die verbliebenen Zweifel auszuräumen, kommt man in meinen Augen jedoch nicht umhin zu erklären, *warum* das Satzglied *dann* an dieser Stelle eingefügt werden kann, das Satzglied *ich* an der gleichen Stelle aber falsch wäre.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus Ich interpretiere die Frage so, dass OP *ich koche* für richtig hielt, weil damit das Verb an Position 2 stehen würde. Das ist nicht der Fall. *Dann* ändert nach folgender Regel die Stellung des Verbs nicht: Adverbien nach Konditionalsätzen stellen keine eigenen Satzglieder dar, sondern fungieren als Korrelate für den vorausgegangenen Nebensatz. (Nachzulesen in [Habermann et al.: Fit für das Bachelorstudium, Grundwissen Grammatik. Dudenverlag, 2009.](https://www.worldcat.org/title/duden-fit-fur-das-bachelorstudium-buch/oclc/320533060) ).